# Get UTC date timestamp from Calendar Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, timestamp

I'm trying to get `Date` for `timezone` in `UTC` format and depend on the user-selected birthplace and `timezone` save it in the database but after setting the timezone and try to retrieve the new  value it's returning the old format, not in `UTC`

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    }
    println("Date: ${calendar.time}")

I/System.out: Date: Sat Feb 26 16:43:08 GMT+02:00 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This Answer uses Java syntax, as I have not learned Kotlin. You can translate easily.)

## tl;dr

Never use `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone`, or the other legacy date-time classes.

Generate text using a formatter object with the *java.time* classes.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG )
    .withLocale( Locale.GERMANY )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nwx1kw).

> 28. Februar 2022 um 10:30:06 NZDT

Retrieve a moment from a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as an `OffsetDateTime` object. Adjust to your desired time zone. Generate text using `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
String output = zdt.format( myFormatter ) ;
```

## Details

You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

**Date-time objects do not have a “format”.** Date-time objects hold date-time values, not text. We use formatters to parse text into date-time objects, and use formatters to generate text from date-time objects.

Get current moment as seen in UTC using [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

For more flexible formatting, convert to an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

And use `OffsetDateTime` class when accessing a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

To see that same moment as viewed through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, assign a time zone (`ZoneId`) to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate text in a format that is automatically localized.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nwx1kw). Notice how the date as well as the time-of-day differs when viewed through the wall-clock time of Japan.

```
instant = 2022-02-27T21:23:27.804471Z
odt = 2022-02-27T21:23:27.804471Z
zdt = 2022-02-28T06:23:27.804471+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
output = lundi 28 février 2022 à 06 h 23 min 27 s heure normale du Japon
```

All of this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

---

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later. Android 26+ comes bundled with an implementation. For earlier Android, access most of the functionality through the "API desugaring" feature of the latest tooling.